# Convexing and Concaving Cylinder Bodies

Tags: modifiers, sculpting

I'm currently working on a Saber Hilt project, and I've hit a roadblock. I'm not overly skilled with Blender, but willing to learn.

My design has two parts, the outer hilt, and inner hilt. What I'm looking for, is how to shrink our expand the middle of the cylinders, so they look like they have been sucked in, or inflated out slightly. I know I can take the long way, and extrude a bunch of sections, and shrink them incrementally, but I get the feeling there is a better and faster way to do so.

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: @JachymMichal Just added one! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use multiple loocuts.

1. Set Pivot center to *Individual Origins*
2. Scale and move the secondary loopcuts
3. Use the *Shear tool* to adjust the rotation.

[image]